# External screen recognized, but black

Tags: drivers, monitors, multi-monitor, intel-graphics

I have a brand new computer (i5-7200U, so Kabylake with a Intel HD Grpahics 620) running Ubuntu 16.10.

And I use an external HDMI screen.

For some reasons, this one is detected (I see it in the Display parameters menu) but it stays black (with a signal because if not, the monitor would turn off).

At work I have another HDMI screen, and I have no problems with this one. I also tried various cables, but the screen stays black.

This screen is working, since I use it with other computers (Ubuntu 16.10, Hackintosh, Windows).

I'm a bit lost about what can I do to solve this issue. Any ideas ?

Here are some details of my configuration:

```
~ % sudo lshw -c display        
[sudo] Mot de passe de bigx : 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       produit: Intel Corporation
       fabriquant: Intel Corporation
       identifiant matériel: 2
       information bus: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 02
       bits: 64 bits
       horloge: 33MHz
       fonctionnalités: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       ressources: irq:126 mémoire:ee000000-eeffffff mémoire:d0000000-dfffffff portE/S:f000(taille=64) mémoire:c0000-dffff
```

So the driver is i915 (from https://01.org/linuxgraphics/ and up to date).

```
~ % modinfo i915         
filename:       /lib/modules/4.8.0-41-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko
license:        GPL and additional rights
description:    Intel Graphics
author:         Intel Corporation
author:         Tungsten Graphics, Inc.
firmware:       i915/bxt_dmc_ver1_07.bin
firmware:       i915/skl_dmc_ver1_26.bin
firmware:       i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin
firmware:       i915/skl_guc_ver6_1.bin
...
```

other outputs:

```
~ % lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:5916] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:15a0]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

and

```
~ % xrandr --props              
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 293mm x 165mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff000dae721300000000
        0e1a0104951d1178028785a457509b27
        0d505400000001010101010101010101
        010101010101b43b804a71383440503c
        680025a510000018000000fe004e3133
        334843452d454e310a20000000fe0043
        4d4e0a202020202020202020000000fe
        004e3133334843452d454e310a200024
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
   1920x1080     60.01*+  59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
HDMI-2 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff004c2d3f0b48385a5a
        081a010380301b782a9561a55552a028
        0f5054bfef80714f81c0810081809500
        a9c0b3000101023a801871382d40582c
        4500dd0c1100001e011d007251d01e20
        6e285500dd0c1100001e000000fd0032
        4b1e5111000a202020202020000000fc
        00533232443330300a202020202001a5
        020311b14690041f13120365030c0010
        00011d00bc52d01e20b8285540dd0c11
        00001e8c0ad090204031200c405500dd
        0c110000188c0ad08a20e02d10103e96
        00dd0c11000018000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000050
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x800      59.91  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08
```

and

```
~ % sudo get-edid | parse-edid                                        
[sudo] Mot de passe de bigx : 
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 1
No EDID on bus 2
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 5
No EDID on bus 6
2 potential busses found: 0 3
Will scan through until the first EDID is found.
Pass a bus number as an option to this program to go only for that one.
256-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 0
If this isn't the EDID you were looking for, consider the other potential busses.
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "S22D300"
    ModelName "S22D300"
    VendorName "SAM"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 8 of 2016
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 480 270
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 30-81
    VertRefresh 50-75
    # Maximum pixel clock is 170MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1152x864, 75Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x800, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1440x900, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1600x900, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz

    #Extension block found. Parsing...
    Modeline    "Mode 8" 74.25 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 0" 148.50 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 1" 74.25 1280 1390 1430 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 2" 148.500 1920 2008 2052 2200 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 3" 74.250 1280 1390 1420 1650 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 4" 148.500 1920 2448 2492 2640 1080 1084 1089 1125 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 5" 74.250 1280 1720 1760 1980 720 725 730 750 +hsync +vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 6" 27.000 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 7" 27.027 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync
    Modeline    "Mode 9" 27.00 720 732 796 864 576 581 586 625 -hsync -vsync 
    Modeline    "Mode 10" 27.00 720 736 798 858 480 489 495 525 -hsync -vsync 
    Option "PreferredMode" "Mode 8"
EndSection
```

What else could I give to help you find my problem ?

Comment: It seems that xrandr revognizes this as hdmi2. Have you try to use hdmi1 output? Laptop edp  screen and hdmi are adjusted for mirror or extended desktop? Do you use hdmi or vga cable??

Comment: Hello George, there is no HDMI-1 output on the laptop, HDMI-2 output works as intended with another monitor. I use HDMI cable. Screens are adjusted to do an extended desktop.

Comment: Strange problem. Your laptop works with another monitor - your monitor works with another laptop , but those two does not work together....Did you try to restart your laptop with the external monitor attached to see if it wakes up?

Comment: By the way in my Debian i have a succesfull extended desktop configuration with my laptop and my external 37'' LG TV , connected as VGA-1 and not HDMI (and also using VGA Cable) with a command like this: `xrandr --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 1x1 --output LVDS-1 --mode 1366x768 --scale 1x1 --left-of VGA-1` - You could also try by root command line  the possibility to achieve something with a similar command.

Comment: Yes as you say, very strange. I still can't​ figure it out

Comment: Did you try to restart with external screen attached?

Comment: Yes, attached and detached, same behavior.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56091/discussion-between-xavier-seignard-and-george-vasiliou).

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried pressing the monitor's menu button? Use it to select HDMI input.

I had a similar problem, completely mystified until I figured this out. Sharing in case you overlooked this.

Comment: Come on! Sure I did. I even restored the factory settings of this screen. Played with every settings with no luck.

Comment: WAT, how the community can give 50 rep to this answer?!! I'd prefer to give 50 rep to George Vasiliou who was much more helpful in his comments than this useless answer!!!

Comment: He commented instead of answered. I don't know who this "Community" is. I could delete my answer if it bothers you

Comment: Hey. This answer was useful to me! I forgot to do that

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem (with the same Samsung screen I think) and I just solved it by unplugging power cable because the menu button did not respond then replugging it and test the button by taping a little randomly on it. It seemed fine so I replug the HDMI cable and it worked!

Comment: Is there a way to do it via script?

Comment: I think no, it is a screen side problem I think so you have to unplug/replug it so it reboots properly.

Comment: Thanks this saved me....

Comment: same here... :) thanks. In my case it was weird because it shown Asus starting logo but not regular content.

Comment: This actually worked for me...

Answer (score 4):

I had to switch from gdm3 to lightdm.

```bsh
sudo apt install lightdm -y
```

Then stop the gdm3 service, which may cause a reboot

```bsh
sudo service gdm3 stop
```

lightdm should be enabled by default and you shouldn't have to start it manually, but if you do:

```bsh
sudo service lightdm start
```

Check the status of gdm3 and lightdm to make sure gdm3 is off and lightdm is on.

```bsh
sudo service gdm3 status
sudo service lightdm status
```

Comment: sidenote: stoping gdm3/lightdm etc does not lead to a reboot.

Comment: For some reason when I stopped gdm3 my system rebooted.  I thought it sort of made sense because there were no other session managers running at the time.

Comment: After 3 years I can finally use a second monitor. Side note that it did mess up my screens when I first rebooted so I had to do some finagling.